# Plot barplot as density plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Could anyone help me to plot the data below as a density plot where `colour=variable`?

```
> head(combined_length.m)
  length                     seq           mir variable     value
1     22  TGAGGTATTAGGTTGTATGGTT mmu-let-7c-5p     Ago1  8.622468
2     23 TGAGGGAGTAGGTTGTATGGTTT mmu-let-7c-5p     Ago1 22.212471
3     21   TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGCATGGT mmu-let-7c-5p     Ago1  9.745199
4     22  TGAGGTAGTATGTTGTATGGTT mmu-let-7c-5p     Ago1 11.635982
5     22  TGAGTTAGTAGGTTGTATGGTT mmu-let-7c-5p     Ago1 13.203627
6     20    TGAGGTAGTAGGCTGTATGG mmu-let-7c-5p     Ago1  7.752571

ggplot(combined_length.m, aes(factor(length),value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(~variable) +
  theme_bw(base_size=16
```

I tried this without success:

```
ggplot(combined_length.m, aes(factor(length),value)) + geom_density(aes(fill=variable), size=2)

Error in data.frame(counts = c(167, 9324, 177, 150451, 62640, 74557, 4,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 212, 6, 1, 4
```

[image]

I want something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qitOs.jpg[image]

Comment: Yes, I got this:    > ggplot(combined_length.m, aes(factor(length),value)) + geom_density(aes(fill=factor(variable)), size=2)
Error in data.frame(counts = c(167, 9324, 177, 150451, 62640, 74557, 4,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 212, 6, 1, 4

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself, not in the comments (you can format it nicely in there and it's easily visible to everyone without reading all comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `factor(length)` for `x` seems to create problems. Just use `length`.

Also, density plots display the distribution of whatever you define as `x`. So by definition the `y` axis is the density at a given value of `x`. In your code you seem to be trying to specify both `x` and `y`, which makes no sense. You can specify a `y` in `geom_density(...)` but this controls the scaling, as shown below. [Note: Your example has only one type of `variable` (Ago1) so I created an artificial dataset].

```
set.seed(1)   # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(variable=rep(LETTERS[1:3],c(5,10,15)),
                 length  =rpois(30,25),
                 value   =rnorm(30,mean=20,sd=5))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=length))+geom_density(aes(color=variable))
```

[image]

In this representation, the area *under each curve* is 1. This is the same as setting `y=..density..`

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=length))+geom_density(aes(color=variable,y=..density..))
```

[image]

You can also set `y=..count..` which scales based on the counts. In this example, since there are 15 observations for `C` and only 5 for `A`, the blue curve (`C`) has three times the area as the red curve (`A`).

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=length))+geom_density(aes(color=variable,y=..count..))
```

[image]

You can also set `y=..scaled..` which adjusts the curves so the maximum value in each corresponds to 1.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=length))+geom_density(aes(color=variable,y=..scaled..))
```

[image]

Finally, if you want to get rid of all those annoying extra lines, use `stat_density(...)` instead:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=length))+
  stat_density(aes(color=variable),geom="line",position="identity")
```

[image]